# Creating settings like the Mail settings in the Settings app

Tags: iphone, uitableview, settings

I want to create some settings much like the Mail settings within the Settings app. These allow you to add mail accounts to the end of the table

```
First screen
  ---------------
+ | add account |
  ---------------
```

When they click on the cell, they are pushed onto a new screen where they fill in a few textfields

```
Second screen
  -----------------
  |(cancel) (save)|    - the toolbar
  -----------------

  ----------------
  | email        |
  ----------------
  |another field |
  ----------------
```

Then when they go back, they can see the new record as well as the 'add account' cell.

```
First screen
  ---------------
  | email   1   |
  ---------------
+ | add account |
  ---------------
```

It need to be in-app rather than within the Settings app. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Apple's CoreDataBooks example: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008405-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

It will give you an idea how how to set up a group UITableView as well as a UITableViewController.

Answer (score 2):

UITableView(Controller) and UINavigationController are your friends here... They are quite comprehensive, so make sure to work through the samples and guides.