# Creating settings like the Mail settings in the Settings app

Tags: iphone, settings, xamarin.ios

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982218/creating-settings-like-the-mail-settings-in-the-settings-app) i want to do create a mail-like-add-account dialog but not as a in-app dialog but as a settings-dialog. does anyone know how to do that? i probably have to link a own UITableViewController in my .plist file somehow? but google does not give me anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware, the only way to get user settings in the Settings.app is to create a Settings.bundle in your app. You can add simple setting functionality plists (tiered if you like) but you can't add extra functionality as you describe.

Another option may be to use [InAppSettingKit](http://www.inappsettingskit.com/)

Comment: I agree with @gnuchu.  You cannot do everything that Apple does on the system.  They are keeping some secrets for themselves.

Comment: well, Siphon does it somehow: http://code.google.com/p/siphon/source/browse/trunk/Siphon4/Resources/Settings/Settings.bundle/Root.plist (<string>addAccountWithSettingSpecifier:fromViewController:</string>), but i need a MonoTouch way!

Comment: Are you talking about the line: <string>addAccountWithSettingSpecifier:fromViewController:</string>?

Comment: @Black Frog: yes, it seems, that the code patches the settings somehow.

Comment: @esskar: The key for that string is InAppAction.  I cannot find anything about that in Apple Docs.

Comment: i checked the code: those InApp* Keys are custom keys that get internally used, to do special stuff. It happens in http://code.google.com/p/siphon/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FSiphon4%2FClasses%2FInAppSettings * but i do not see what has to be done that that customization code is executed.

Comment: I think the custom key in IASK are executed when the Settings.bundle is accessed from inside the app but they won't be executed when accessed from Settings.app. I could be wrong though - Ill have to check when I get home.

Comment: i checked more: the code in the siphon rep is from http://inscopeapps.com/#inappsettings, which is pretty much the same as IASK. So you seem to be right, no solution for that so far!